# Delete all Sheets except one, loop within a loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that contains a list of URLS for spreadsheets and the sheet name that I want to keep.

The idea is that I delete all sheets within each of those spreadsheets except the sheet I want to keep.

I have written a script but I can not seem to get it to work, I get an error message of "invalid argument line 20" but I can not figure out why.

I have pasted my code below, any help would be appreciated.

```
function DeleteImportedData(){
  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("URL's")
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh1 = s1.getSheetByName("MasterSheet")
  var copy = sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  var getHeader = sh1.getRange(1,1,1,25).getValues()
  for (var j = 1;j<s3.getLastRow(); j++){
  var filterName = s3.getRange(j+1, 1).getValue()
   var id = s3.getRange(j+1,2).getValue()
   var open = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
   var sheet = open.getSheets()[0];
   var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
   var sh3 = open.getSheetByName("STSOR - "+filterName)
  }
for (i = 0; i <= sheets.length; i++) {
  switch(sheets[i]) {
  case sheet.getSheetName() === sh3:
  break;
  default:
  open.setActiveSheet(sheet[i]);
  open.deleteActiveSheet;
  open.deleteSheet(del)
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Your snippet start at line 1 ?

Comment: @WaximCorp I'm sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: you have a problem line 20, I'm just checking if the problem is coming from : "open.setActiveSheet(sheet[i]);"

Comment: @WaximCorp sorry yes, that is the line giving me the error

Comment: Can you please specify how many sheets and how they are called in your spreadsheet so we can better replicate this?

Comment: I have another script that creates and deletes spreadsheet based on a few different variants, it will also import data onto each spreadsheet based on the sheet name, but each spreadsheet will have only one sheet, the name is the same as the name of the spreadsheet

Comment: A couple of things, at line 20 you are setting the sheet[i], have you checked that this value is not null or the sheet belongs to a different spreadsheet? At line 21 you are not invoking the function. At line 22 what does **del** mean? it's not declared anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the first sheet from the list Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 - Sheet2 changes its index to Sheet1. So it is better to delete sheets from the end

try to use the reverse loop

```
for (i = sheets.length-1; i >=0 ; i--){
  ... your code ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestion however I still get the error on line 20, I am beginning to think it may have something to do with some of the spreadsheets only having one sheet.

Comment: the error occurs because the 'open' variable is declared inside the first loop, and it is called in the second loop. It seems to me that you need to put your second loop in the body of the first loop. And for better understanding of the task it's better to see at least a screenshot of a part of your URL's sheet - then there will be more opportunities to help with the code

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong between your variable sheet and sheets and your second loop.
Try this way :

```
for (var j = 1;j<s3.getLastRow(); j++){
  // your code

  // second loop inside the first loop
  for (i = 0; i <= sheets.length; i++) {
    switch(sheets[i]) {
    case sheets[i].getSheetName() === sh3: //instead of 'sheet'
      break;
    default:
      open.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]); //instead of 'sheet'
      open.deleteActiveSheet;
      open.deleteSheet(del)
    }
  } // close first loop
} // close second loop
```

but I think the second loop would be cleaner that way (IMHO):

```
for (i = 0; i <= sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() !== sh3) {
    open.deleteSheet(sheets[i].getSheetName());
  }
}
```

If this code doesn't answer your question, please provide more informations about your spreadsheets